# Snapshot/Save GPU Drivers

Tags: windows-xp, gpu, amd-radeon

Since I'm running XP/32-bit, my GPU drivers are quite fragile. I've spent several hours trying to back up and restore from old versions, on at least two separate occasions.

Writing down the device drivers is not enough. In the short term, I would like to somehow save, zip, backup, snapshot, or *something* so that if I need to reinstall my OS in the short-term, I have a reliable way to get the drivers.

ATI's website doesn't have the install kit anymore, and I don't have it saved; I googled, but didn't find the exact same version.

How can I backup/save my drivers so that I can reinstall them later?

Comment: Just save the installation package.  You will need to find a mirrior for the time being.

Comment: @Ramhound as I said, I don't have the installer, nor can I find the exact same version of that installer on the web.

Comment: • `I don't have the installer`   What about the CD? Do you still have that?     • `Nor can I find the exact same version of that installer on the web`   Can’t you use a newer one? Even for discontinued products, they keep and make available *at least* the last supported/released driver.   • It would be helpful if you specified what video-card you have.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you properly, you are looking for older driver versions, if so, you can find them here: [Previous Catalyst™ Drivers for Windows XP](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/previous/Pages/radeonaiw_xp.aspx)

And the SDK: [AMD APP SDK Download Archive](http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/pages/AMDAPPSDKDownloadArchive.aspx)

You can store them on Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. so you always have access to them.